# nginx ssl not working - 404 File Not Found

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, nginx, fastcgi

environment:

Linux Server - ubuntu
Web Server - nginx
Scripting - php5, fastcgi
Ports - default - 80/443
Php framework - codeigniter

i have a website which has been made with codeigniter, and is working absolutely fine under http, i have setup a ssl certificate and I am unable to get the subsequent pages work, home page is working fine in https.

FYI: The website is made with url rewrite, I dont know whether Nginx or FPM or Codeigniter handles the rewrite, but we have working urls as http://domain.com/contact

In Nginx log file i see a 404 page not found error. If I create a directory under the home folder as test and create a file as hello.php, I am able to see it through HTTPS and HTTP, but not other links are working.

I assure that -

1. I am pointing to the right folder in http, https
2. The key file does not has a password
3. I have included the chain / root certificates
4. I have no firewall / proxy / cache server in between

I dont know which one among nginx/codeigniter/php-fpm is handling the url rewrite, and i am sure the error is due to url_rewrite not working in https/ssl mode.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You should post your full nginx conf file. Otherwise its difficult to tell whats going on.

If the url rewrites are redirecting over http and you want your site to be moved to https, then you should do a HTTP 301 moved permanently.

```
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```